# Twitter API 1.1 and wrong rate limits for users/lookup and for users/show

Tags: twitter

I'm working with the twitter API 1.1 but I found this strange behavior:

The `remaining value` of the rate limit after a call to `users/lookup` is not decremented. If I use this call, when I check the rate limit status I don't see any changes:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/lookup.json?screen_name=twitterapi,twitter
```

and I can't understand why the rate limit for the function `users/show` works only using the parameter `user_id` and not using `screen_name` (why the API developers have imposed this constraint?)

To check the rate limit I use the call:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/application/rate_limit_status.json?resources=users
```

Comment: did you check the `limit` value or the `remaining` value in the response?

Comment: the remaining value obviously :)

Comment: hmm.. - what about just feeling happy? Dealing with hit limits isn't just fun?

Comment: Ahaha thank you Alex I feel better now!